# GemBox Document adding special chars into a boomark

Tags: c#, newline, bookmarks, gembox-document

I am trying to load text into a bookmark into a word document and save. The bookmark can be a large amount of text with new line characters.
Here is the code:

```
String text = "Some text with \n new \n line chars \n";
ComponentInfo.SetLicense(GEMBOX_DOCUMENT_LICENSE_KEY);
DocumentModel document = DocumentModel.Load(fileTemplate);
document.Bookmarks["bm_1"].GetContent(false).LoadText(text);
```

However the resulting PDF document that saves prints out "Some text with \n new \n line chars \n".
What changes do i need to make to `text` to make it render properly?

Comment: Are you still having difficulties with this?

Comment: @MarioZ thanks for your response. It was a little more complicated than i made it out to be. The `String text` was actually coming from a JSON file that had escaped the \n's and was not interpreting it as special chars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what issue you have, I tried the following:

```
String text = "Some text with \n new \n line chars \n";

DocumentModel document = DocumentModel.Load("input.docx");
document.Bookmarks["bm_1"].GetContent(false).LoadText(text);

document.Save("output.pdf");
```

I have used the following input DOCX:

[image: input DOCX file]

And I got the following output PDF:

[image: output PDF file]

Can you send me your input and output files?